# Sort NSMutableArray of custom objects in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

i tried to sort array of custom objects. when an array contains one object, it returns the sorted Array with an object. But if an array contains multiple object, it crashed

```
class Plans:NSObject{
   var price:Int

   var name:String?
   .. 
   ..
   .. 
}


func price(array:NSMutableArray,sortKey:NSString)->Int{
        var sortDescriptor:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: sortKey, ascending: true)
        var sortedArray:NSArray = array.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDescriptor])//Crashes
        var apt:Plans = sortedArray.objectAtIndex(0) as Plans
        return apt.price
}
```

function call:

```
self.price(array,sortKey:"price") //array contains array of Plans objects
```

Crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<pjct.Plans 0x7fb8a7bb7af0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key price.'
```

Comment: Your code actually works for me. Which version of xcode you are using? How did you initialise the `array` variable?

Comment: i am using Xcode 6.1. i mapped the json response into array and tried to sort the array by price

Comment: It is very likely the array does not contain any object of `Plans` type. You should show us the code you used to convert the json response into the array.

Comment: i tried to print array elements. all objects in the array are Plans object which has 'price' key

Answer (score 3):

First make `Plans` class implements is `Comparable` and `Equatable`. Here is how:

```
extension Plans: Comparable {}
extension Plans: Equatable {}
```

Then implement two function:

```
func ==(lhs: Plans, rhs: Plans) -> Bool {
    return lhs.price == rhs.price
}

func <(lhs: Plans, rhs: Plans) -> Bool {
    return lhs.price < rhs.price
}
```

Now you can use standard operators to sort your array. Here is how

```
let sortedArray = (objcArray as AnyObject as [Plans]).sorted(<)
```

Or if you don't want to implement this protocols you can simply sort array like this:

```
let sortedArray = (objcArray as AnyObject as [Plans]).sorted {$0.price < $1.price}
```

Comment: i get NSMutableArray does not have a member named sort

Comment: cast it to `Array<Plans>`

Comment: how can i cast. i tried this. (plansArray as Array<Plans>).sort(<). i get an error as "Immutable value of type Array<Plans> only has mutating members sort"

Comment: Sorry I used wrong method. Instead of `sort` use `sorted` method. It will create a new sorted array from your array. I will update may answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Finally i was able to figure out the issue. I can't sort array that contains Int value. so i changed "price" from Int to NSNumber

```
var price:Int
```

to

```
var price:NSNumber
```

now it works.